# Prove that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) = 0$ for some $c \in A$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x)f(x) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let $g$ be a function with domain $A$ and $f$ be a bounded function on $A$. Prove that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) = 0$ for some $c \in A$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x)f(x) = 0$.

I was given the definition of a bounded function: A function $f$ is considered a bounded function on $A$ if there is a certain value $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in A$.

Also, I was given that I cannot simply apply the product rule for limits, and write that
[\lim_{x \to c} g(x) f(x) = \left( \lim_{x \to c} g(x) \right) \left( \lim_{x \to c} f(x) \right).]This is because the rule only applies when both $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exist.

I am wondering how to do this question without using the product rule. I have tried to use the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of limits and it has got me nowhere.

Comment: Hint Let $h(x)=g(x)f(x)$, then $|h(x)-0|=|g(x) \, f(x)| \leq M |g(x)| \ldots \leq M \frac{\epsilon}{M}$..

Comment: Fix $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - c| < \delta$ implies $|g(x) - 0| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}$. Then for $|x-c| < \delta$, how about $|g(x)f(x)-0| = |g(x)f(x)|$?